# Laravel & Vue warning issue

Tags: css, laravel, vue.js

I have worked on Laravel & Vue js project.

This is Laravel code

The code works well but there is a warning in developer mode (inspect)

**Laravel View** code

```
@extends('layouts/app')

@section('content')

    <div id="app">
     </div>

@endsection
```

**app.js** code

```
const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes});
const app = new Vue(Vue.util.extend({ router }, App)).$mount('#app');


app.js:74791 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app
warn @ app.js:74791
query @ app.js:79817
./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.dev.js.Vue.$mount @ app.js:86018
./resources/js/app.js @ app.js:86329
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
0 @ app.js:86576
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
(anonymous) @ app.js:84
(anonymous) @ app.js:87
app.js:74791 [Vue warn]: Property or method "single" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <Overlap> at resources/js/components/OutwardComponent.vue
       <Root>
```

Comment: Are you sure your route is pointing to that view?

Answer (score 0):

Your div that needs to reference the Vue should be in Layout file,
It might be possible that your div is rendering after the Vue Initialization.
Put `<div id="app"></div>` in `layouts/app` file and see if its gone or not.